# ASP.NET Failing to enter data into database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, hosting, web-hosting

I recently uploaded my data driven ASP.NET application to a asp hosting service called SmarterAsp.com.

Everything in the website works fine, all but 1 feature, data can't be entered into the database.

However when using a gridview control to see data in the database the data is displayed perfectly and I can even insert, update and delete data through the gridview.

I uploaded my database in a separate space on the hosting service and I was provided with a connection string, I replaced all connection strings in my application with the provided connection string.

It works fine in my IDE, the problem only came once I uploaded the website to the hosting service.

Here is my C# code for inserting data into my database:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@DataSource=SQL5004.Smarterasp.net;Initial Catalog=DB_9DE115_hmkdatabase;User Id=DB_9DE115_hmkdatabase_admin;Password=YOUR_DB_PASSWORD;"))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO Clients(ClientName)VALUES(@ClientName)");
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientName", TextBox1.Text.ToString());
            connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
}
```

And here is the error I get when attempting to insert the data: 
    Server Error in '/' Application.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

**Description:**

> An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current
>   web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:**

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26
>   - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

My first thought was that it's a problem with the connection string, but the connection string works fine with the rest of the application. I can enter data into my database through the gridview add function but I cannot enter data using the C# codebehind page. As I said it works fine in my IDE, the problem only came once I uploaded the website to the hosting service.

Thanks in advance for the help guys. You guys are real life heroes!

Comment: check your connection string in server name (data source).

Comment: @Kaushik Maheta As I said in the post, the connection string works fine everywhere else but in the above code. So the problem is not my connection string.

Comment: Check this article and see if this helps you out  [Error establishing a connection to SQL](http://support.sysonline.com/support/solutions/articles/4000016491-errmsg-a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-connection-to-sql)

Comment: @marnouxmanser, Can you put your working code (display data) here?

Comment: The code that works is the premade HTML code that is written when a grid view is created.

Answer (score 0):

I sorted out the problem. My problem was where I initialized the connection string and where I opened the connection. I initialized the connection string at the top where the page is initialized. And then replaced where the connection string was with connection.open();

Thanks for all the help guys!